# VS for Mac doesn't build if Proxifier is running

Tags: msbuild, xamarin-studio, visual-studio-mac

Can not build in Visual Studio Mac (Used to be Xamarin)

Nothing builds or cleans. Not even a console app. I am using version 7.1.5 on macOS 10.12.6.

I uninstalled and reinstall and still the same issue.

`Error: Build failed. See the build log for details.`

This is the error in the build log:

```
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-d15-3/bockbuild-d15-3/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /private/tmp/source-mono-d15-3/bockbuild-d15-3/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /private/tmp/source-mono-d15-3/bockbuild-d15-3/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /private/tmp/source-mono-d15-3/bockbuild-d15-3/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-d15-3/bockbuild-d15-3/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.Project+<>c__DisplayClass142_1+<<RunMSBuildTarget>b__0>d.MoveNext () [0x00113] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5123/7afedcae/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/Project.cs:1200 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Update1:
This only happens when I am using  Proxifier Version 2.21
http://www.proxifier.com/mac/

Update2:
Filed as a bug here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60008
Also contacted proxifier.